# Sheet reference on cell

Tags: excel

I have three sheets: s1, s2, s3.
On s1 and s2 I have values on column A.

On s3 I have a sheetname on column A, either "s1" or "s2", depending on the row.
I want to fill my B column with either the s1 value or s2 value, depending on the value of column A.

Manually it would either be:
='s1'!A1 or ='s2'!A1

But as I need to get the value of the A column of s3 where the sheetname is written it would be something like
='s3!A1'!A1

But of course, it is not working. Do you know how I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is what INDIRECT is for:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A1")
```

To make it Draggable:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A"&ROW(A1))
```